# how to use multiple data-frames for training and testing purpose in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have multiple data-frames e.g windows 1,windows 2.......windows 6. i have used sliding window technique to split dataset. each window contains 336 records. i have concatenate all windows in a data-frame with the name of 'big data'. now i want to train multiple windows one by one in a loop and append(row wise) all windows records in train and test will return testing. how to do that  by using looping condition? please help me..

```
n_rows = Len(windows 1)

train_idx = n_rows

test_idx = train_idx + n_rows

big data = windows 1.append([windows2,windows 3,windows4,windows5,windows6], ignore_index=True)

big data=pd.DataFrame(big data)

train = big data.iloc[:train_idx, :]

test = big data.iloc[train_idx: test_idx, :]
```

i have different data frames e.g windows 1.....windows 79. each window contains 336 records e.g for windows 1(index start with 0-336)records, windows 2(index start with 337-672) and so on. now i want to use all data frames one by one for train like windows 1 train and save into train variable and windows 1 train with 336 records and predict next 336 records which is save in test variable. next windows 2 train with next 336 records but in train variable we want to append windows 1+ windows 2 (row wise append) now the train variable for second time execution will be total 672 records and then train the whole 672 rows and test next 336 records which is save in test variable. actually i want to use this approach for classification method. i want to apply this method with looping wise.. hope is that clear?

Comment: The description of what you want to achieve is not really clear. Can you write a simple example with the input and expected output?

Comment: The description is defined above.